# bounded partitions and bounded signed partitions of integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, asymptotics, partitions, enumerative-combinatorics

Define a bounded signed partition of length $m$ and of bounded height $h$ of an integer $n$ by a relation:

$$n = \pm a_{1} \pm a_{2} \pm a_{3} \pm \dots \pm a_{m}$$ where each $a_{i}$ is a integer in the range $[0,h]$

Define a bounded partition of length $m$ and of bounded height $h$ of an integer $n$ by a relation:

$$n =  a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + \dots + a_{m}$$ where each $a_{i}$ is a integer in the range $[0,h]$

Are there relations for the number of both partitions of $n$ in terms of $m$, $h$ and $n$?

Are there strong asymptotic forms?

In the plain bounded partition case what is the asymptotic if each $a_{i} < h_{i}$ and $h_{i} = h_{i+1} - 1$? (ordering on the maximum sizes and not on the summands)

Answer (score 5):

Since you include 0 and do not ask that the a_i are increasing with i, your questions
are morally equivalent to counting lattice points in the m dimensional plane 
$n= \sum x_i,$ except you want those inside a certain m-cube of side length
h or 2h, depending on when sign matters.  This suggests the correspondence between the two problems of
adding h to all coordinates in a signed partition to get an unsigned partition
for n+ mh with values in 0 to 2h.

For the unsigned portion and for n at most h, the answer is a simple
combinatorial arrangment giving (n+m-1) choose (m-1) such partitions,
and the same value serves as a weak upper bound when n> h.  Although you can check
the literature for this, be mindful that most references will assume an ordered
partition, meaning $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \ldots$ .

Comment: what about the last portion?

Comment: I don't know, except that you have a prism instead of a cube.  I remember a web page of Kevin Brown (formerly at seanet.com) that attempted this problem.  You might find some asymptotics there.

Comment: This is part of what I remember: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337.htm .  He may have more.